# How to ensure read and write consistency of data

Tags: cnosdb

When writing, it is always done to write to the master node. How to read from CnosDB, whether to read from the master node or the replica node; What is the read logic if the master node is hung before electing a new master node? If allows reading from the master node, it may lead to failure, while reading from the slave node may cause data inconsistency issues.